# Mid-Square with all bits set

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there a positive 128-bit integer whose square has all middle bits equal to 1?

(The "middle bits" are naturally the 65th bit through the 192nd bit, defining
the 1st bit as the least significant bit of the full integer.)

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in this question?

Comment: It's simplified from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096308/unreachable-middle-squares and http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42923/mid-square-hash-quality

Comment: Sure, any number <2^32 has the property you wish.

Comment: Is a 128-bit integer necessarily at least $2^{127}$? (or can the first few bits be zero?)

Comment: Smaller numbers are fine.  Any of the 128 bits can be zero.

Comment: I don't see any way of answering this other than by a brute force computation (although some brute force methods are quicker than others). We can replace 128 by any even number 2m and the question still makes sense, and has a positive answer for 2m=8,10,20,22,24,26,28,...but negative answers for other even numbers <= 28. The calculation will take too long (for me) for 128 and the question just seems like an idle one to me so I don't think I'll be using the work cluster to investigate it...

Comment: What is 192nd bit of 128-bit integer?

Comment: @Max, in many implementations often the 192d bit of a 128 bit integer is 0, although it can be undefined. What is requested is a consecutive swath of bits from the square of a 128 bit integer, which seems interesting when the integer is appropriately large.  Gerhard "Will Try Some Short Cases" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: @Kevin, if you have the cluster to brute force a calculation involving 2^28 trials , this one can be resolved with little more.  Just iterate through square roots of ta+d for t from 0 to 2^32 -1 and a and d appropriately chosen, and see which ones are close enough to integers.  Gerhard "What's A Billion Between Processors?" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: I think I need a loop of size $2^{64}$ (see my partial answer below). What am I missing? Can you explain more precisely?

Comment: Oops.  That's 2^64 - 1, not 2^32 - 1.  Never mind. Gerhard "Anyone Got A Billion-core Multiprocessor?" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The confusion was that "128-bit" here does not refer to the size of computer arithmetics (in which a square would be 128-bit integer as well), but just to the size of an given integer while the arithmetics is done traditionally.

Comment: [Problem (as stated) solved!](https://mathoverflow.net/a/418082/122065). Perhaps the question needs to be re-generalized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a positive 128-bit integer whose square has all middle bits equal to 1?

***YES***. One is AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB5555555555555555<sub>16</sub>, which square is 71C71C71C71C71C7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF8E38E38E38E38E39<sub>16</sub>.

---

It's asked if there are integers $n$ such that $0<n<2^{2k}$ and $(n^2\bmod2^{3k})\ge2^{3k}-2^k$, in the case $k=128/2$.

As noted in [comment by Max Alekseyev](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1073379?noredirect=1), that holds for $k\equiv 4\pmod6$ (thus including the question's $k=128/2$), because the integer
$$n=\frac{2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1}-1}3$$
does the trick. It's representation in base $4$ consists of $k/2-1$ digits $2$, one digit $3$, and $k/2$ digits $1$. It holds
$$n^2=\frac{8^k-1}{9}2^{k+2}+\frac{8^{k+1}+1}9$$
which representation in base $4$ consists of the digit $1$; the digits $301$ repeated $(k-4)/6$ times; the digit $3$ repeated $1+k$ times; the digit $2$; the digits $032$ repeated $(k-4)/6$ times; the digit $1$. It follows the center $2k$ bits are set, with three more on the left and one more on the right.

We can't use this to conclude exactly how many $n$ there are, or/and for other values of $k$, or/and for an arbitrary value in the middle of the square.

Here is a brute force search for $k\le21$:

| $k$ with a solution | #solution(s) | possible $n$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 10110101<sub>2</sub> |
| 5 | 2 | 0010110101<sub>2</sub> 0101101010<sub>2</sub> |
| 10 | 2 | 10101010110101010101<sub>2</sub> 11100010010001100011<sub>2</sub> |
| 11 | 4 | 0010101010110101010101<sub>2</sub> 0011100010010001100011<sub>2</sub> 0101010101101010101010<sub>2</sub> 0111000100100011000110<sub>2</sub> |
| 12 | 3 | 000111000100100011000110<sub>2</sub> 010010001110001000101011<sub>2</sub> 110001101110000001111001<sub>2</sub> |
| 13 | 3 | 00001110001001000110001100<sub>2</sub> 00110001101110000001111001<sub>2</sub> 01100011011100000011110010<sub>2</sub> |
| 14 | 1 | 1010001000110010100010011000<sub>2</sub> |
| 16 | 1 | 10101010101010110101010101010101<sub>2</sub> |
| 17 | 2 | 0010101010101010110101010101010101<sub>2</sub> 0101010101010101101010101010101010<sub>2</sub> |
| 19 | 1 | 11110010011001000101100100110110000011<sub>2</sub> |
| 21 | 4 | 010100000101011011101010011000101011000111<sub>2</sub> 011101100111011110011000000000010111000101<sub>2</sub> 101000001010110111010100110001010110001110<sub>2</sub> 111101110010111001100001001101110110100001<sub>2</sub> |

We see and could prove that if $n$ is a solution for $k=k_a+1$ with $n<2^{2k_a}$, then $n$ is a solution for $k=k_a$. And if $n$ is a solution for $k=k_a+1$ with $n<2^{2k_a+1}$ and $n$ even, then $n/2$ is a solution for $k=k_a$. That explains why more often than not, if $n=n_a$ is a solution for $k=k_a$, then $n=n_a$ or/and $n=2n_a$ is/are a solution for $k=k_a+1$.

Comment: In fact, this works for any $k\equiv 4\pmod{6}$ with $$n=\frac{2^{2k+1}+2^{k+1} - 1}3$$ and $$n^2 = \frac{8^k-1}{9}2^{k+2} + \frac{8^{k+1}+1}{9}.$$ Notice that $6$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $9$.

Comment: fgrieu and MaxAlekseyev:  Wow, another math miracle! I would, of course, love to see a general solution for any k which is a power of 2.  To start, do you have an idea to solve the next k = 256/2 ?  Another interesting topic might be whether there are any more solutions for k = 128/2.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

I can't see any tricks to do this other than a brute force computational approach. The naive approach would be to loop from $2^{96}$ to $2^{128}$ squaring each integer and checking. A more efficient approach in practice is to start with the number $2^{192}-2^{64}$ and then loop up to $2^{256}-2^{64}$ in steps of $2^{192}$ -- this only involves a loop of length $2^{64}$ rather than one of length $2^{128}$. For each term $n$ in the loop (thought of as a good approximation to a square) one computes the smallest integer square which is at least $n$ and then checks to see if the difference is less than $2^{64}$. But a loop of length $2^{64}$ is too long for me.

Here's some pari-gp code which takes an even length $n=2m$ and solves the analogous problem of searching for $n$-bit numbers which have 1's from the bit controlling $2^m$ (the "$m+1$st bit, I think, in the language of the OP) to the bit controlling $2^{3m-1}$.

```
g(n)=m=n/2;d=2^(3*m)-2^m;r=0;forstep(i0=d,2^(4*m)-2^m,2^(3*m),if(issquare(i0),s=sqrtint(i0),s=sqrtint(i0)+1);if(s^2-i0<2^m,print("yes -- s=",s);r=1;break()));if(r==0,print("no"));r
```

It (rather inelegantly) prints the smallest number it finds, if it finds one, and returns 1 or 0 depending on whether it finds one or not. It runs to $n=60$ quickly.

What motivated me to post this as an answer was the observation that in fact for most values of $n$ it could find an $n$-bit number which did the job. There's nothing for 2,4,6 but 181 works for 8 and 10 (this is related to the famous fact that $181^2=2^{15}-7$). There are then failures for $n=12,14,16,18$ but after that the garden gets rosier -- the numbers 699733 (twice),1853638,707276,170076312 work for 20,22,24,26,28, we have another failure at 30, and then 2863355221 works for 32,34; another failure at 36, success at 38, failure at 40 and then another big string of successes -- everything from 42 to 62 works. For example 363103060890424251 works for 60 and 62; in binary the square of this is 110010110010001100111000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111001111101101110100101010011001 . This somehow indicates the problem in general -- you have a bunch of 1's in the middle but things look pretty random outside that region. The loop I posted above brute forces the first string of digits and then looks for the nearest square (because there will be at most one string of digits at the end making the number square).

I do not know a more sensible way of approaching this problem, however given that for most small values of $n$ there did seem to be a solution one might be cautiously optimistic that such an integer could exist. I suppose that on average the moment one passes $2^{96}$ the middle digits are kind-of random, so one might ask instead if you have an event which has a $2^{-128}$ chance of happening but you have $2^{128}-2^{96}$ attempts at it, what are the chances of you being lucky, and they're about $1-1/e$. So a sporting chance!

Comment: Indeed. Except for my arithmetic mistake in my above comments I was thinking along these lines.  More generally, one could look at (given d) certain constrained solutions of a^2 +c = bd^3, but I don't know enough theory to follow that up. Gerhard "Off To Practice Some Bit-shifting" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: With reference to a^2 + c = bd^3, It seems bd must be very close to a square, and that Pell equations might say something about which n=2m have solutions.  Gerhard "Perhaps This Will Inspire Someone" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman -- I don't understand the relevance of the equations with the cube in. Can you explain more?

Comment: Let d=2^k. For m=2k even, the question boils down to finding c and b less than d such that bd^3 - c is a square of an integer .  For such an a, a/d is close to sqrt(bd). Perhaps Pell equations or rational approximation of square roots might say what b are permissible.  Gerhard "Looping Brain Instead Of Code" Paseman, 2017.01.15.

Comment: a/d is  "close" to sqrt(bd) but at first glance it doesn't seem to be anywhere near close enough to say anything useful. Pell gives powerful things but we're doing Pell for bd and there are too many possibilities for b before we can get started, so I don't immediately see how to get it to give anything yet. There's a chance that the loop is the only way to go I guess.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to point out why the case of middle bits being all ones is somewhat special and different from other fixed values of them. Also, there is an approach for finding a suitable numbers that may not exist for other fixed values of middle bits.

I'll use the notation of Kevin and additionally require that $m$ is even, say, $m=2k$ (in OP's question we have $m=64$ and $k=32$).

We need to find integers $x,y$ such that $0\leq x,y<2^m$ and 
$$x\cdot 2^{3m} + (2^{3m}-2^m) + y=z^2$$
for some integer $z$. In other words, we have
$$0<(x+1) - \frac{z^2}{2^{3m}} = \frac{(2^m-y)}{2^{3m}} < \frac{1}{2^{2m}}.$$
Factoring the l.h.s. as $(\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{z}{2^{3k}})(\sqrt{x+1}+\frac{z}{2^{3k}})$ and noticing that the latter factor is at least 2 (for $x>0$), we get
$$0<\sqrt{x+1} - \frac{z}{2^{3k}} < \frac{1}{2^{4k+1}}.$$
This tells us that $\frac{z}{2^{3k}}$ is a very good rational approximation to $\sqrt{x+1}$.

The above analysis may suggest to search for $\frac{z}{2^{3k}}$ among convergents and semiconvergents to a square root of an integer. We can base this search on two facts:

- A continued fraction for a square root has special forms: $[a;\overline{2a}]$, $[a;\overline{b,2a}]$, $[a;\overline{b,b,2a}]$, $[a;\overline{b,c,b,2a}]$, $[a;\overline{b,c,c,b,2a}]$, etc.
- Denominators of (semi)convergents satisfy a simple recurrence relation (involving terms of the continued fraction).

So, for each of the above continued fractions, we may to try find values of $a,b,c,\dots$ such that $2^t$ with $t\leq 3k$ appears among the denominators of (semi)convergents, from which will further get $z$ (as the numerator times $2^{3k-t}$) and hopefully solve the problem.

**Remarks.**

1. Values $t\leq 2k$ may work only for convergents, not semiconvergents (the rational approximation in this case becomes so good that only convergents may satisfy it).
2. There is a number of underwater stones here such as (i) not every set of values $a,b,c,\dots$ guarantee that we have a a continued fraction of the square root of an integer (in general, it's the square root of a rational); (ii) semiconvergents may not guarantee that the approximation is well enough for our purposes; etc.

Comment: Several years on, but I feel obliged to point out that this approach has a relatively fatal flaw: There are many, _many_ $x$ between $x=0$ and $x=2^n$, and most of them won't have very simple continued fraction expansions — the expected value of the period of the expansion of $\sqrt{D}$ is (roughly) $\Theta(D^{1/2})$, so trying to search on suitable $a, b, c,\ldots$ will turn up a relatively small number of ;'candidates' unless we blow out our search more-or-less exponentially.