# Unreachable middle square

Tags: nt.number-theory

For positive $k$, define the function $H_k$ over the integer interval $[0\dots2^{2k})$ with
$$H_k(n)\;=\;\left\lfloor{n^2\over2^k}\right\rfloor\bmod 2^{2k}$$
that is, keeping the middle $2k$ bits of the $4k$-bit square of $2k$-bit $n$. See [Donald Knuth's TAOCP](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Euno/taocp.html), chapter three (at start of volume 2) for references about use of [middle square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method) as a building block in pseudo-random number generators.

For large $k$, e.g. $64$ or $128$, can we exhibit $h\in[0,2^{2k})$ demonstrably reached by no $H(n)$?

---

If $n<2^{k/2}$, then $H_k(n)=0$. By a counting argument, it follows that several $h$ in $[0\dots2^{2k})$ are reached by no $H_k(n)$.

Numerical experiments show that such unreachable values are relatively dense just below $2^{2k}$ (more than they are just above $0$).

```
  k (dec)       Six highest unreachable values (hex)
     1            3            1
     2            F            D            B            7            5            3
     3           3F           3B           39           36           35           31
     4           FD           FC           FB           F7           F5           F3
     5          3FB          3F9          3F7          3F6          3F3          3F1
     6          FFF          FF8          FF7          FF3          FF2          FEF
     7         3FFF         3FFD         3FFB         3FFA         3FF9         3FF6
     8         FFFF         FFFD         FFFC         FFF5         FFF4         FFF1
     9        3FFFF        3FFFC        3FFFA        3FFF8        3FFF7        3FFF3
    10        FFFFD        FFFF9        FFFF8        FFFF6        FFFF5        FFFF1
    11       3FFFF9       3FFFF7       3FFFF6       3FFFF3       3FFFEF       3FFFED
    12       FFFFFD       FFFFFB       FFFFF7       FFFFF6       FFFFF4       FFFFF2
    13      3FFFFEF      3FFFFEE      3FFFFED      3FFFFE8      3FFFFE5      3FFFFE3
    14      FFFFFFD      FFFFFFB      FFFFFF5      FFFFFF4      FFFFFEF      FFFFFEA
    15     3FFFFFFF     3FFFFFFD     3FFFFFFA     3FFFFFF6     3FFFFFF4     3FFFFFF1
    16     FFFFFFFD     FFFFFFFC     FFFFFFFA     FFFFFFF9     FFFFFFF8     FFFFFFF7
    17    3FFFFFFFD    3FFFFFFF8    3FFFFFFF7    3FFFFFFEF    3FFFFFFED    3FFFFFFEC
    18    FFFFFFFFF    FFFFFFFFB    FFFFFFFFA    FFFFFFFF7    FFFFFFFF4    FFFFFFFEC
```

---

Note: This is the unsolved portion of an old [question on crypto-SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42923/555). A simplified [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/259663/122065) asking if $H_{64}(n)$ can reach $2^{128}-1$ was answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Heuristically the proportion of unreachable values tends to $\frac{1}{e}\approx 0.36788$ as $k$ grows.